# Is it a good idea to put function type as values in HashMap?

Tags: android, performance, kotlin

I have a question about the performance of putting **function type** as a **values in HashMap**.

I've saw my colleague's code being written likes this:

```
var mHandleMap = HashMap<String, (WebView,String) -> Unit >()

fun init() {
    mHandleMap.put(URL1, doSomething1)
    mHandleMap.put(URL2, doSomething2)
    mHandleMap.put(URL3, doSomething3)

    override fun onPageFinished(webView: WebView, url: String) {
        mHandleMap.forEach { (key, urlFunc) ->
            if (urlStr.contains(key)) {
                urlFunc(webView)
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}

private val doSomething1: (WebView) -> Unit = {
    ...
}

private val doSomething2: (WebView) -> Unit = {
    ...
}

private val doSomething3: (WebView) -> Unit = {
    ...
}
```

If it was me, my code may looks like this, this kind of code will be more intuitive for me:

```
val url = request!!.url.toString()
when {
    url.contains(URL1) -> doSomething1()
    url.contains(URL2) -> doSomething2()
    url.contains(URL3) -> doSomething3()
}
```

His code looks really fashion, but I worried about if there are any problem inside.

Could anyone help me to point out is it a good way to do this or not?

Answer (score 1):

I would use your way because it's more concise, that hashmap way doesn't improve the code in any way, besides remember that those function object once compiled into bytecode will be that: Objects, maybe the difference is trivial with the sample you are providing but I would presume the performance to suffer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't do what his code does when more than one of `URL1`/`URL2`/etc is contained in `url`; you'll call only the function corresponding to the first such key, he'll call functions for all of them.

Aside from that, performance difference is likely to be very small compared to any talking to outside world (e.g. if you make a request to any of those URLs). But even trivial differences can add up, and especially for Android or other cases with limited resources.

Plus, if his behavior is the intended one, something like `Array` or `List<Pair<...>>` is still more memory-efficient than a `Map`, unless there's code looking up by key somewhere.